# IE Giving Incorrect, Random 403 Errors

Tags: internet-explorer

We've got a very weird problem that I'm wondering if anyone else has come across.  Our customer portal sometimes has images missing when being viewed on IE, this also happened once with a CSS file as the page came across unstyled.  Doing some research in the IE11 diagnostic tools these missing files are "returning" a 403, access denied error.  Now, I know that this points to an issue on the server, but if you refresh the page sometimes the images will appear again, and possibly different ones will give 403 errors, plus viewing the site in any other browser (Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Chromium) doesn't produce any problems, whatsoever, so I'm pretty sure it's specific to IE - I think we've seen it on versions 9, 10 and 11.  I don't know if it's related, but I suspect so, but all our site is served up over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you please share an example?

Comment: Unfortunately not (if I could have done so, I would have) as you need to log in to the server, so our data-confidentiality requirements prohibit being able to give a practical example.  I have found other accounts of this happening, but unfortunately I didn't save the URLs and can't find them again.  It's happening on multiple machines, both inside your company firewall and outside from my home connection.  The only possible commonality is all the machines have our company group policies on them.

Comment: I totally appreciate that I've not given as much information as would be ideal, but we don't know if this is just affecting us, or whether it's affecting our customers or making our portal look bad, so I thought I'd take a punt and hope that someone else who has seen this problem sees this question.